# How to output a raw JSON page from a Kentico Repeater in Portal Design mode

Tags: web-parts, kentico

In Portal Mode how can I cause a page to output just the data of its Repeater web part without the page wrapper asp.net form, etc?

I've set page Template inheritance to none, unchecked header inheritance, but to no avail, am still getting theme elements, asp.net form, html tag head, body and the norm.  I'm looking to get rid of all those peripheral html elements and keep just the repeater output which is raw JSON.

What I'm trying to achieve is to output raw JSON to page using a Repeater Web Part while keeping the Repeater in the CMS Design UI where it's easy to manage by Admins. The RAW JSON will be picked up by a JQuery.get(..) or equivalent to read JSON and parse it, as per usual.

I've tried combining the Kentico Custom Response web part with a Repeater on the same page, but the Custom Response blows away any other page output of course.

I'm willing to dip into ASPX + Portal template combo mode if necessary, but want to keep using Kentico web parts in the Design interface to produce the data.

I found a [Custom Response Repeater web part on DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/custom-response-repeater) however would rather manage the Design mode myself because I might want to throw some additional web parts in there.

Ultimately if it's not doable or involves too much complexity I'll use a good old ASP.NET ASHX Handler to produce what I need from the Kentico API and leave Kentico Design mode out of the equation altogether.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a custom web part on the Kentico Marketplace which will allow you to tell the page what type of output you want, it's called the [Web part to API Converter](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/webpart-to-api-converter).  Download that web part, import it and add it to your page template.  Be sure to change you page template so it DOES NOT inherit any other page or template.

Then you associate that Web part to API converter web part to your listing web part and it's like magic (or basic coding), it converts your aspx page to a "raw" format of whatever output you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you do not want to use existing web service /CMSPages/WebService.asmx? You can create your own method and return you json there:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetMyData(string parameter = "")
{
    // Get your data
    DataTable myData = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems("customtable.sampletable").Result.Tables[0];
    // return JSON
    string JSONString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
    this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    this.Context.Response.Write(JSONString);
}
```

But I would recommend doing it with [Web API](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/using-asp-net-web-api-with-kentico)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The reason I don't want to use the existing service is stated in the question: I want the repeater that generates the json available to the Kentico admin.